# 22.04 Fingerprint login keeps losing my fingerprints

Tags: login, fingerprint-reader, pam

I have set up fingerprint login for my 22.04 installation. It has been working well for a few weeks but now rejects all login attempts.

When I go to 'Users' in settings, the Fingerprint Login has become Disabled. If I click on the arrow to pop up the modal window, none of my previously recorded fingerprints are showing and I only have the option 'Scan new fingerprint'.

If I try and scan a new fingerprint selecting one of the finger options that I have previously used, it goes through the motion of recording my fingerprint and then reports 'Failed to enroll new fingerprint' and syslog reports "printd[8939]: Device reported an error during enroll: Finger was already enrolled as 'FP1-20221206-7-73B34153-jfowlie'"

I can register a fingerprint under a new finger option, but it does not seem to persist through a reboot. That finger option will then report the same re-registration problem.

I've tried to find where the fingerprints may be stored as I cannot delete them through the gui. However, I've had no success. I'm really not sure how the pieces come together to provide this service.

Answer (score 0):

Try these two:

- Disable "Predesktop Authentication" in BIOS (Security -> Fingerprint)
- Reset Fingerprint Data in BIOS (Security -> Fingerprint)